# Do I need to follow the bean naming conventions when using JPA annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I'm using JPA's annotations to specify my mapped fields, like so:

```
public class PersistedEmployee {
  private Integer id;

  @Id//Plus some @GeneratedValue cruft in the real example
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(final Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Does that ID *need* to follow the `getFoo` bean naming convention? Or are the annotations sufficient for identifying how to map this POJO?

The underlying provider is Hibernate, in this case, but I'm also curious if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "bean naming conventions"? What are you actually wanting to achieve? Do you want the database to have a different name for this column? Or do you want the name of the `get` method to be different?

Comment: Depends. If you use field level access, the the accessor methods don't matter; and don't even need to exist.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear Ideally I'd like to have accessor methods like `foo()` rather than the JavaBeans-style `getFoo()`. The examples all show get- and set- style property accessors as far as I can see, so it's unclear if it's required or just convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA supports two ways to access properties. Either through getters and setters or through reflection directly accessing the field.

If you use the first, the getters and setters need to follow the proper naming convention, if you use the second, they don't have to exist, and you can use whatever accessors/mutator you like.

What access type is used is defined by the place where you put the `@id` annotation. If it is on a field, field access is used. If it is on a getter/setter property access is used.

Answer (score 0):

JPA spec.

```
The persistent state of an entity is accessed by the persistence provider
runtime either via JavaBeans style property accessors (“property 
access”) or via instance variables (“field access”).
```

It's publically available, so if using JPA you really ought to get it, or a book/documentation that presents it.